# 検索が、ダブルクォートが(勝手に)付与されてうまくうごかない

Tags: バグ, 機能の要求

検索窓で検索する際に、以下の不具合に遭遇しています。

- 検索窓から検索した際に、既存入力部分がダブルクォートで囲まれ、その常態で検索をかけてもなにも Hit しない。

順をおって説明しますと、

#### 1. トップバーの検索窓で適当な文字列を検索する。検索結果が表示され、再度クエリを投げる用に今検索した文字列がダブルクォートされて入力された状態になる。

[image: 最初に mac で検索した場合。検索自体は mac で行われ、検索まどには "mac" が入力されている。]

#### 2. ダブルクォートされた状態で検索を行うと、何も Hit しない

[image: ダブルクォート付で検索した場合]

### なので

- これは、とても検索しづらい UI です。改善できないでしょうか。

Comment: Mac(10.13.1)/Chrome(62.0.3202.94)/シークレットモードで再現しないのですが、あれ？コレって直ってます？

Comment: 昨日問題が再現することを確認(Windows 10/Chrome 62.0.3202.94)しましたが、本日は再現しませんでした。直ったかも？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

今朝確認したところ、直っていました。新しい挙動では、ダブルクォートがつかなくなっています。